# Including Date Range Selector for Google Analytics api implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics-api

I've been trying to implement the date range selector by following the demo in https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/custom-components/ But, whenever I try to test my script, I get errors.

For these scripts,

> /public/javascript/embed-api/date-range-selector.js"
>
> /public/javascript/embed-api/components/date-range-selector.js"

I get a 404 error saying that the scripts are not found. Whenever I check my sources in the browser, the generated .js files are blank.

Additionally, I tried this:

> https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/public/javascript/embed-api/components/date-range-selector.js

And I got an error saying that gapi was undefined.

How am I supposed to include this js to my project so I can implement it? I've also already disabled AdBlock if that means anything.